# use HorizontalBarChart.class Unable to display all text

Tags: android

Using MPAndroidChart: v4.1.0, HorizontalBarChart.class horizontal bar chart, using setValueFormatter to display the left text, but the text will be displayed adaptively. You must zoom in to view the text. Is there any way to display it all?

No solution found, sorry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW9YA.png)
I hope so

[Actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCZGw.png)

Comment: Try to increase the size of the chart so that the text is not cut off. You can also adjust the horizontal spacing between each bar in the chart to create more space for the text. Additionally, you may want to consider decreasing the font size of the text to make it fit better within the chart.  Another option could be to rotate the horizontal bar chart to a vertical bar chart, which may provide more space for the text to display fully.

Comment: I think it has enough space, but it doesn't show haha